# Angular 2 form validation Error Scroll

Tags: angular2-forms

I want to implement the reactive form validations in angular 2.When user clicks on submit button the page will scroll up to the required error.

```
@ViewChild('focuserror') errorElement: ElementRef;
      ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(this.errorElement.nativeElement.querySelector('.ng-invalid'), 'focus');
       }
```

Is this the right code?
It's throwing error

- typeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of null

Answer (score 13):

you can do this:

```
formSubmitFunction() {

  const firstElementWithError = document.querySelector('.ng-invalid');

  if (firstElementWithError) {
    firstElementWithError.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
  }
}
```

you can use any class you have used in form validation.

Comment: Awesome, worked for me! Only mod I've done is `document.querySelector('textarea.ng-invalid, input.ng-invalid, select.ng-invalid')` , otherwise the first element with `ng-invalid` class is `form` element

Comment: how to add offset to this. as i have got a header in there. and the scrolled element is behind the header. thus not visible???

Comment: @ShubhamShaw, please see my answer for adding offset and other key improvements.

Answer (score 0):

I used ElementRef instead of document.querySelector because ElementRef is backed by a render-specific element. In the browser, this is usually a DOM element, read more at [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef).

```
constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}
```

In your submit or click method, get the first element with a validation error. Be careful that the form will also have .ng-invalid until all inputs are valid.

```
const firstElementWithError = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('form .ng-invalid');
```

If you have any fixed navbar, you need to take its height in account as well.

```
if (firstElementWithError) {
  const labelOffset = 50; // This is your offset based on the height of your navbar, etc...

let scrollTopPosition = controlEl.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY - labelOffset;
```

Unlike document.querySelector element, window.scroll allows you to specify the top position when scrolling.

```
  window.scroll({ behavior: 'smooth', top: scrollTopPosition });
}
```